# How to separate any punctuation that combine with word into single word?

Tags: java, string

Assume the sentence is `There are playing, they are brothers.`

Is there anyway to separate the punctuation in to single word the output as below:
`There are playing , they are brothers .`

Comment: Yes. Yes there is. Split the string.

Comment: Yes I got try in by using 'split("\\s+")' but it will not show the result I want.

Comment: You're splitting on the wrong expression.

Comment: how its looks like i have tried many ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
String str = "There are playing, they are brothers.";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\s*([,.?!\"'])\\s*", " $1 "));
```

Yields:

`There are playing , they are brothers .`

This regular expression will replace any punctuation mark which might have lead/trailing spaces with a space, followed by the same punctuation mark and another space. This block: `[,.?!\"']` denotes all the punctuation marks you can change. You can add/remove to your hearts content. The `\W` flag could also do the trick, but it will change a set of specific characters (anything which is not a letter, digit or underscore).

Answer (score 0):

You could try regular expressions?

Something like:
`s/(\w)([,.])/\1 \2/g`

It's essentially a non-word character (this might be \W), followed by the punctuation being found, replacing with group 1, space, group 2.

I've made a demo, [available here](http://regexr.com?31pgs).

Comment: @cchua: Fixed slightly & added a link to a demo.

Comment: ok thanks for your demo, but I still don't understand how to code it .

Comment: Look into Java's Matchers & Patterns :)